# How to map XML schemas to C/C++ code?

Tags: c++, c, xml, mapping, parsing

What the best way to map XML schemas to C/C++?

Here is an example:

------ C/C++ -----

```
    struct zone {
       char *var_name;
       float var_value;
    };
```

------ XML -----

```
    <xs:element name="zone">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="Var_name" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="var_value" type="xs:decimal"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

Comment: I would suggest mapping xs:string to a better construct, `std::string` if you are using C++ or a couple `char*` and `int` if you want C compatibility.

Comment: Do you mean: how to map a C++ abstract syntax tree to an XML structure?

Answer (score 6):

[CodeSynthesis XSD](http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsd/) is an XML Schema to C++ compiler that does pretty much exactly what you are looking for. If you want a more lighter-weight version, there is also XSD/e which is geared more towards mobile/embedded development.

Answer (score 2):

[Xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/) works pretty well as a library for pulling in the XML document.  (You didn't say what OS or dev environment so this is pretty generic C and C++.)

From there a struct/class per element would be a good mapping.  If you have a lot of XML elements to parse, I'd try looking for, or writing, a code generator to pull in the XML and spit out your class or struct definitions.  Once you get it right once, doing it for any XML element is a piece of cake.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I am working on solaris with gcc and windows xp with vc++6. As I have got two programs (one works with xml and other with c++), I am tying to couple them to run some simulation studies.  Thanks again for your help,

Answer (score 0):

Code generation from XML such as this is best achieved using [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT). If you have [libxslt](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/index.html) installed you can use [xsltproc](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc2.html) to perform the transform. Make this a pre-build step in your build process to generate the source code.

How about this:

**structs.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="zone">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Var_name" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="var_value" type="xs:decimal"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="zone2">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Var_name" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="var_value" type="xs:decimal"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

**makestructs.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="/xs:schema/xs:element">
struct <xsl:value-of select="@name" /> {
            <xsl:for-each select="xs:complexType/xs:sequence/xs:element">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="@type = 'xs:string'">
    char*
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="@type = 'xs:decimal'">
    float
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:value-of select="@name" />;
            </xsl:for-each>
};
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The stylesheet is indented for readability. but you'll want to remove some whitespace so it doesn't appear in the output.

Comment: thanks for reply?  then ho to map C/C++ code? can you give an exmple/ thanks again

Comment: You mean that you have C struct definitions that you want to map to XML schemas? The question suggested the inverse so perhaps you should clarify.